# Verify solution to ODE

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the ODE

$$\left(f''(x)+\frac{f'(x)}{x} \right) \left(1+f'(x)^2 \right) = f'(x)^2f''(x)$$

and I already know that the solution to this ODE is given by
$$f(x)= c  \cdot arcosh \left( \frac{r}{c} \right) + d$$
where $|c|<r$ and $d \in \mathbb{R}.$

The problem is I want to show that this is an actual solution by direct integration (so I want to derive it) and not just verify it by plugging it in. Does anybody know how this can be done?

After rearraging as Daniel Fischer proposed, I end up with

$$f''(r) = -\frac{(f'(r)^3+f'(r))}{r}$$

Comment: Let $y(x) = f'(x)$. Rearrange the equation so that you get the form $y'(x) = \dotsc$. It's a separable ODE, determine $y$ from that, integrate once more to get $f$. Doesn't look particularly pleasant, however, I'm afraid.

Comment: now you can substitute $f'=g$ and get bernoulli eguation for $g$ which is known how to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\left(f'' +\frac{f'}{x}\right)(1+f'^2)=f'^2f''
$$
multiply by $x$
$$
(xf''+f')(1+f'^2) = \left(\dfrac{d}{dx}xf'\right)(1+f'^2) = xf'^2f''
$$
then we have
$$
\frac{1}{xf'}\left(\dfrac{d}{dx}xf'\right) = \frac{f'f''}{(1+f'^2)}
$$
thus
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\ln(xf') = \frac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dx}\ln(1+f'^2)
$$
which is
$$
\ln (xf') = \frac{1}{2}\ln(1+f'^2) + C
$$
or
$$
x^2f'^2 = C_1(1+f'^2)
$$
or
$$
(x^2-C_1)f'^2 = C_1\implies f' = \sqrt{\frac{C_1}{x^2-C_1}}
$$
or
$$
\dfrac{df}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{C_1}}\right)^2-1}}
$$
you should see what the solution of the last equation is.

Comment: impressive you can see this without any change of variable. it is magic.(+1)

Comment: @abel not so much magic its repeating a series of manipulations and finding one that works lol..but as you should know I hold your opinion in high regard so I appreciate it!!

Comment: I don't know how people can do things like this!  Amazing, Chinny84!  ***Endorsed!!!***

Comment: @RobertLewis Thanks man. The only tip is to keep trying a bunch of steps and one will hopefully stick( I have been stuck on a personal ode which may or may not have an analytical solution that has eluded me for ~5yrs, I may share it on here and get an answer)..but I would save amazing for Andrew wiles et al. ;).

Comment: Yeah, I don't have the patience for it, but I tbink I know what you mean . . . that's why I went into qualitative theory . . . and don't worry, there's plenty of "amazing" to go around!

Comment: @robertlewis If you have some time I would like to discuss what you do :). Expand my horizons.

Comment: Curious . . . I was just thinking the same thing with regard to yourself . . . my email address is on my user page, as I see yours is on yours . . . feel free to use mine, as I will yours, and soon . . . we can begin a Hardy-Littlewood thing! ;-)  Cheers!

Comment: Correction:  my email address is on my MO user page; there I go by drbobmeister!

Comment: Haha .. I hope we can set up a partnership like that one!! Exception I have not done serious mathematics for some time (if you call a phd in plasma physics real mathematics). I will get your email off your account and hit you up tomorrow(pretty late in my tz).